# C programming - pointers used in functions that work with multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2 functions:

```
double** transpose(double **a, int r, int c){
    static double trans[100][100];
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
            trans[j][i] = a[i][j];
    return trans;
}

double(*matrixMultiply(double a[10][10], double b[10][10],
    int rowA, int colB, int colARowB))[10]{
    static double c[10][10];
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < colB; j++){
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < colARowB; k++)
                c[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
        }
    return (double*) c;
}
```

While I do understand the algorithms, can someone explain me what these 2 functions return (types, pointers...) ? The second seems to return an array, but I thought that functions in C can't return arrays ...

Getting really confused with these pointers...

Also why are the arrays (`trans` and  `c` ) declared as static? As far as I get it, when you declare a variable or a function with static it can't be imported for use in another file, but that's defenetely not the case here  ...

Comment: `double **` is **not** a 2D array and cannot point to one. A pointer is not array. And no, you cannot pass arrays to/from functions. But you can pass pointers to arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions are attempting to return pointers to arrays.  Both are *doing it wrong* and fail to compile on my system.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the `transpose` function, we're returning the *expression* `trans`.  `trans` has type "100-element array of `T`", where `T` is "100-element array of `double`".  It's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", which in this case is "pointer to 100-element array of `double`" (`double (*)[100]`), ***NOT*** "pointer to pointer to `double`", (`double **`).

The compiler *should* complain about that function.  Mine does, like so:

```
gcc -c -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall transpose.c
transpose.c: In function âtransposeâ:
transpose.c:7: error: return from incompatible pointer type
```

In the `matrixMultiply` function, `c` has type "10-element array of 10-element array of `double`", which "decays" to "pointer to 10-element array of `double`" (`double (*)[10]`).  The second function has the right return type - `double (*)[10]` - but then they ***MESS IT UP*** by casting `c` to `double *` in the return statement, and we get the same error as before:

```
gcc -c -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall matrixMultiply.c
matrixMultiply.c: In function âmatrixMultiplyâ:
matrixMultiply.c:11: error: return from incompatible pointer type
```

They *should* have just written

```
return c;
```

and everything would have been alright.

The way to read that second function definition is as follows:

```
        matrixMultiply                           -- matrixMultiply
        matrixMultiply(                   )      -- is a function taking
        matrixMultiply( /* some params */ )      -- some parameters (omitted for brevity)
       *matrixMultiply( /* some params */ )      -- returning a pointer
      (*matrixMultiply( /* some params */ ))[10] -- to a 10-element array
double(*matrixMultiply( /* some params */ ))[10] -- of double
```

Note that the only reason either function has a hope of working (once the type issues are straightened out) is that both `trans` and `c` are declared `static`, meaning that their lifetimes extend over the entire program, not just the lifetimes of their respective functions. Without that `static` keyword, they would *cease to exist* after their enclosing functions return, and those pointers would become *invalid*.

This is not necessarily good practice - these functions are no longer re-entrant and not thread-safe.  It would be better to pass the target arrays as parameters to the functions, but be aware that a pointer to a 10-element array is a different, incompatible type from a pointer to an 11-element array - if you have to deal with arrays with different numbers of columns, that could get tricky.  VLAs can help with that:

```
void transpose( int r, int c, double arr[r][c], double trans[c][r] )
{
  ...
}
```

assuming you have VLAs available (you should on C99 and C2011 systems, although they've been made optional in C2011).  If you don't ... this gets harder.

Comment: Another problem with returning a pointer to a static object, as is done here, is the potential for unexpected aliasing.  That's a particular risk in the OP's case -- if the return value from one of those functions is passed back to that function as a parameter in a subsequent call, then the actual behavior is unlikely to be what was expected.  Or if a separate and independent call to either function is performed, it may come as a surprise that the pointer returned by a previous call afterward points to different data.

Comment: Thank you a lot  for the answer and for the time you took to write all this down. It's all clear now. I am sorry for the mistakes in the functions but, in my defence ,they are not mine. I copy-pasted them from the yesterday course of programming. Seems the teacher was not paying attention... ohh well.

Comment: @ROBlackSnail: C is almost uniformly taught poorly, by people who themselves were taught poorly, and array/pointer semantics are one of the places where a lot of misinformation and bad practice have metastasized.  It's not a great *learning* resource, but bookmark the [current online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C language standard - if nothing else, it will tell you how stuff is *supposed* to work.